# copy gallery image to project files Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I am new in Objective-C and I want choose one image from a Gallery and I want get the name and the extension and copy that image to my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIimagePicker

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    if ([mediaTypeStr isEqualToString:@"photo"])
    {
       if ([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage])
       {
           // images    = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];
           _images      = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
           UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];;
           img          =[self scaleAndRotateImage:img];
           [_images addObject:img];

           //  Save Photo to library only if it wasnt already saved i.e. its just been taken
           [self.alAsstlibrary saveImage:img toAlbum:@"FOlder name" completion:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
           {
              if (error!=nil)
              {
                  //NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
              }
           } failure:nil];       
       }
       else
       {
           //NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = %@", info);
       }
   }
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this follow these steps.

1. Get the image

   ```
   - (void) getPicture:(id)sender 
   {
       UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       picker.delegate = self;
       picker.allowsEditing = YES;
       picker.sourceType = (sender == myPic) ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
       [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
       [picker release];
   }
   ```

You will get the image in imagePickerController delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo 
{
    [self save:image];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

2. Save image in documents

   ```
   -(void)save:(UIImage*)image
   {
       NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
       NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name
       [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
   }
   ```

Get document path

```
- (NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name]; 
}
```

3. Get the Image

   ```
   NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
   ```

Comment: when i call getPicture? @Imran

Comment: Whenever and wherever you need just the get the image and use it

Answer (score 0):

write these in viewdidload or on the buttons click event as per your need..

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;//by writing YES here you can edit image also..
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+y, y, width, height)];
[imgview setTag:i];
imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[imgview setClipsToBounds:YES];
[self.view addSubview:imgview];
```

write these in your .m file..

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


  //if you write picker.allowsEditing = YES; than write info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] in BELOW line....

  UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  imgview.image = chosenImage;//set selected image in your imageview

  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
{
  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

i hope it helps..